# I'm trying to use a @classmethod with filter() in ndb and receiving a error. NDB newbie

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a custom User model with this classmethod.:

```
@classmethod
def by_name(cls, name):
    u = User.query().filter('name =', name).get()
    return u
```

And I am getting this error.:

```
TypeError('Cannot filter a non-Node argument; received %r' % arg)
```

This is My first time using NDB and the code worked with db and all(). So I know this is a simple fix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [NDB cheat sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/edit?pli=1) to the rescue:

```
u = User.query(User.name == name).get()
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and answer!